# Meaning of "just about everybody else has" in this context

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, ellipses, conversational-deletion

> — I ever tell you how much she depends on you?
>   — I ever tell you what an asshole you are?
>   — Nah. But that's okay, just about everybody else has.
>   They both laughed.

Is it "...everybody else has told", or what? I cannot be sure.

Actually, I wanted to ask about the meaning. Is it saying that "... everybody else has told me that I am an asshole" or something else?

Comment: I think this is "general reference".

Answer (score 6):

The utterances

- *- I ever tell you how much she depends on you?*
- *- I ever tell you what an asshole you are?*

Are missing the initial (and totally predictable) *Did* at the beginning; that's what the hyphen represents. This is called ***[Conversational Deletion](http://linguistlist.org/ask-ling/message-details1.cfm?asklingid=200332668)***, and it works from the beginning of a sentence, optionally deleting any completely predictable word, then optionally deleting the next one, and so on, until it runs into a word that's not predictable. Then it has to stop.

The ***I*** in these utterances could also be deleted in conversation, since it's clear what's being asked.

- *- Ever tell you how much she depends on you?*
- *- Ever tell you what an asshole you are?*

Some other examples, with example numbers from Chap. 1 of the dissertation in the link:

- (16) Gotta go now.
- (17) See you next Tuesday.
- (18) Too bad about old Charlie.
- (19) No need to get upset about it.
- (20) Been in Ann Arbor long?
- (21) Ever get a chance to use your Dogrib?
- (22) Ever get to Japan, look me up.
- (23) Good thing we didn't run into anybody we know.
- (24) Last person I expected to meet was John.
- (25) Wife wants to go to the mountains this year.

The utterance *Everybody else has,* on the other hand, is not merely colloquial like Conversational Deletion; it's an example of **VP Deletion** under identity. The Verb Phrase that gets deleted is something like

> *told you how much she depends on you and what an asshole you are.*

which is made up of the verb phrases from the previous sentences. These are past tense; but *Everybody else has* uses *has* instead of *did*, so it must be a Perfect construction. That means past participle *told* (used after *have*), instead of infinitive *tell* (used after *did*).

Comment: +1. Very interesting information. But I don't think the hyphens here represent the missing *Did*. I think they represent direct speech. I also think that the first two sentences are uttered by two different people.

Comment: That doesn't matter. All native English speakers (at least American English) can do this kind of shortening. And what the hyphens represent is irrelevant, too. Writing is technology; speech is natural.

Comment: People, people. Please stop referring to dashes as hyphens. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The options are:

- "...everybody else has."  (the rest is elided because of parallelism, the redundant can go unsaid.
- "...everybody else has told you." (nothing is elided, and it makes a complete sentence)

Just "...everybody else has told" doesn't work; 'tell' requires an object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; The implied full form of the sentences would be:

```
[Did] I ever tell you how much she depends on you?
[Did] I ever tell you what an asshole you are?
Nah. But that's okay, just about everybody else has [been repeatedly telling me what an Asshole I am].
 They both laughed.
```