# When did "Alright?" become a greeting in UK English?

Tags: etymology, slang, cultural-phrases

Who remembers when and how "Alright?" became a greeting in UK English?

Do you remember the first time you heard it? Can you remember *when* that was? What was the context? Was there a particular celebrity or TV show that made it so popular?

Comment: Weird. We never use "alright" as a greeting here in the US.

Comment: Alright or all right (UK, informal) Generic greeting. ***"All right"*** apparently comes from a question (i.e. "are you all right?", "are things all right?") so it seems like more of a synonym for how are you. Then again, a response is often not expected.

Comment: On the US side, I think I may have first heard it used in [The Wire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0306414/). (Where it was pronounced "aieet".)

Comment: @Sun I expect what you heard is the word we typically spell "*a'igh*t" or "*aight*". It's used as an acknowledgement or to indicate assent -- basically another way to say "*ok*", but at the moment considered cooler -- but, like, *ok*, it's not used as a greeting.

Comment: @Dan Bron 'All right' certainly is: **all right** exclamation (GREETING)

› UK informal: used to greet someone at the same time as asking if they are well:
"All right, John?" "Not bad thanks, and you?" [[Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/all-right)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sun and I were going back-and-forth in the context of American usage (see my first comment). I understand in the UK you can say "all right" to greet someone (but I didn't until this question was posted!).

Comment: @ermanen Not really related.  "Alrighty" is a colloquial use of "alright" that has been around for at least a century. I'm looking for the origin of "Alright?" as a greeting, which seems to have occured fairly recently.

Comment: @Dan Bron Harry Potter uses the conversational deletion at the end of [the film version, at least, of] 'Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone'. 
Harry: Alright there, Ron? / 
Ron: Yeah. You? / 
Harry: Alright. Hermione? / 
Hermione: Never better

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't know what a "conversational deletion" is (but now in gonna look it up), but I note that HP is primarily a British franchise, so their usage doesn't really pertain to how we do it in AmE. Also, guilty admission: I've never seen a HP movie or read any of the books. I'll stick with my Tolkien, thank you very much!

Comment: ... See John Lawler's answer at [Meaning of 'just about everybody else has' in this context/](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58443/meaning-of-just-about-everybody-else-has-in-this-context/58445#58445).

Comment: ***Alright, mate*** This affectionate phrase can leave some Americans feeling slightly paranoid, as they might perceive alright, mate! to be a question, rather than a casual greeting. In other words, saying alright, mate! to an American tourist might lead them to think you're asking them if they're feeling okay. Oddly enough, the American equivalent of this phrase is what's up, dude!, which conversely leaves us Brits feeling paranoid for much the same reason. ***Alright, mate! = what's up, dude!*** http://www.lostinthepond.com/2013/03/5-everyday-british-phrases-that-confuse.html#.VUZ4wotdaK0

Comment: Focus, people: What is the ORIGIN of this usage? WHEN (and how) did "Alright?"/"All right?" become a greeting?

Comment: @SunJul - I think the origin is explained in my first comment. The issue is, when this intuitive usage of alright  started ? Very interesting question btw.

Comment: @Josh61 Good point, I should clarify my question.

Comment: As Josh said, this is the equivalent of `Sup`, or `What's up?`.

Comment: But, we do, @Dan Bron.

Comment: @LittleEva We do what? Do you greet your friends with "all right"? As in, those are the first words you speak upon meeting them? Hey, if you do, more power to you. I never have, however!

Comment: @Dan Bron - That message was sent in good humor and I mean no condescendence. I was addressing your initial comment. Thought you might appreciate my answer ... a little. :-)

Comment: @LittleEva I hadn't even noticed you'd posted an actual answer! +1 from me!

Comment: @Dan Bron - Thank you. Sometimes I do greet and reply with a variation of "alright." I love the poetry and creativity of the nuance and surprises of English hybrids, tribal/clan patois, and especially the African-American ebonics. Especially the politically subversive nature of much of it. In many respects these incredibly resilient peoples figured out that their  freedom and survival depended on making the spoken-tongue *their* tongue

Answer (score 2):

I've been living out of the UK for 8 years and was baffled when I returned recently to find shop assistants asking me if I was alright. Oddly in a northern accent, even here in the south - "Ya alright?" The first time this happened I answered,"I'm fine" and they turned away and served someone else - so that's not the right answer! I never heard it when I used to live in UK and still have no idea how to respond. I assumed it was a northern expression popularized by soaps such as Coronation Street.

Comment: Coronation Street is a great tip! I'll bet it documents precisely the point at which alright?-as-greeting popped into the language.

Comment: @SunJul Is that sarcasm?

Comment: I don't really follow British TV but have heard it on Extras, which went on air in 2005. That is just a short time before you left.

Answer (score 1):

***Alright or all right (UK, informal) Generic greeting.*** "All right" apparently comes from a question (i.e. "are you all right?", "are things all right?") so it seems like more of a synonym for how are you. Then again, a response is often not expected. –

***All right*** *used as a greeting: ‘hello’, ‘how are you?’* appears to have a quite old origin. [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/5485?redirectedFrom=All%20right#eid) cites a usage as early as 1868:

> - 1868   D. M. Mulock in Good Words June 335/2   *William's first greeting at his own door was always his wife's face... ‘All right, my darling?’*
> - 1943   R. Sullivan Dark Continent v. 41   *‘Awright, pal!’ the bartender called to him. ‘What'll it be?’*
> - 1989   Financial Times 20 May (Weekend Suppl.) p. xxiii/1   *She looked this imposing gentleman straight in the eye..and said: ‘Alright, mate?’*
> - 2004   C. Bateman Driving Big Davie xii. 117   *He came up, smiling. ‘All right? I was looking for you.’*

From (www.effingpot.com/slang)

> - [All right](http://www.effingpot.com/slang.shtml)? - This is used a lot around London and the south to mean, "Hello, how are you"? You would say it to a complete stranger or someone you knew. The normal response would be for them to say "All right"? back to you. It is said as a question. Sometimes it might get expanded to "all right mate"? Mostly used by blue collar workers but also common among younger people.

A note on British vs American usage:

[Alright, mate](http://www.lostinthepond.com/2013/03/5-everyday-british-phrases-that-confuse.html#.VUdk2WNdaK1):

> - This affectionate phrase can leave some Americans feeling slightly paranoid, as they might perceive alright, mate! to be a question, rather than a casual greeting. In other words, saying alright, mate! to an American tourist might lead them to think you're asking them if they're feeling okay. Oddly enough, the American equivalent of this phrase is what's up, dude!, which conversely leaves us Brits feeling paranoid for much the same reason. ***Alright, mate! = what's up, dude!***

Comment: Nice! I've never heard this in the US. Is it common all over UK? Do Aussies/Kiwis use it?

Comment: @Mitch - av far as I know it is a UK expression. Our friends from Australia and New Zealand might help us with this issue.

Comment: Interesting. So, while its current ubiquity in the UK may be recent, it has apparently been lurking in the language for a long time.

Comment: When I spent several months in London in 2003, I don't think I ever heard "Alright?" as a greeting. (It sounds so odd to an American I am sure I would have noticed it.) When I was back in London for a short trip in 2013, it seems like I heard it everywhere -- even the lady at the airline ticket counter greeted customers with "Alright?"

So what was it that happened in those 10 years that made "Alright?" such a popular way to say "Hello" in UK English?

Comment: @SunJul -probably from TV  Tropes: *Used irreverently as a greeting towards women, "All right Darlin'?"*  http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StockBritishPhrases

Answer (score 0):

Though I am unable to supply a date, the origins of “alright,” in the OP’s sense, lie in African-American/Brit Vernacular English (aka: *ebonics*). “Alright,” or any of its variations have significant currency in urban minority and hip white communities, and prison/jail populations. Examining the origin and meaning of this word is not simple as there are numerous articulations that share subtle commonalities and differences, based upon context, most notably in the Jamaican patois. Here are a few (from the U.S.).

### alright = awright = aight = aite = Irie

1. Used to indicate acknowledgement or acceptance; OK
2. Generic greeting or response to greeting.

> Urban Dictionary:
>
> 08) Instead of saying "hello" or "hi" anymore, some socially hip people decided to use "Alright" accompanied by the famous "sup" nod as a way of communicating to lesser mortals.
>
> Some people think that when someone says "Alright?" to them, they should respond with how they are. Do not do this. You will be exposed as an uneducated idiot.
>
> 11) A common greeting, and response to a greeting, in the New Orleans, Louisiana area. Can be used interchangeably with other common greetings, such as where y'at and what it is. Often heard from passers-by on the street.
>   All versions and variations found in [The Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=alright)

IRIE (Jamaican/Rastafarian): good, fine, okay, hi, happy, pleasant, high, alright;  [Irie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irie) and 
[Irie](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/irie)

Whether with or without complete knowledge of its esoteric interpretations, this expression can be used as a greeting or response alternative for hello, all right, good, fine, I’m alright, etc. However, on deeper level its origins are far more spiritual.

Irie is a Jamaican noun meaning good, excellent, great and good quality. Rastafarian “I-dren” (brethren) have their own language and one word that you will hear frequently is “Irie.” Rastafaris developed their own version of the Jamaican dialect in which “I” is a frequent prefix. For example “I and I” or “I-man” meaning (RELATIONSHIP) I or myself and “I-dren” meaning children or brethren.

• “I and I” simultaneously means (1) you and I (2) the Great Spirit or All That Is. Use as you would ‘I’ but carries the additional "flavor" of a radical-inclusivity.

• “Ites” means the heights of "I and I."

• “Irie” is an adjective form of “Ites,” meaning the same thing.

• “Yes I” is a Rasta term meaning "positive vibration."

Rastas also believe in the concept of "One Love" meaning, everyone should have the same love for everything, i.e., yourself, family, humans, animals, nature, etc. This concept and belief ties in very closely with the concept of "I and I" because it once again stresses the evils of its contrast, i.e., separation.

"I" as prefix also makes any word become more spiritual and sacred. "Irie" is a great example of this, because "Irie" is the ultimate positive.

Antonym: Hurtin (ebonic spelling), English "hurting" meaning, in need of something, i.e., "He is hurtin" (in need of relief) from some type of physical, emotional, spiritual separation, deprivation of well-being, or "pain."

While I have had difficulty authoritatively documenting some of what I assert, due to either or both a paucity of documentation or my rudimentary computer-skills, all that I have chosen to include here is based upon personal experience.

Comment: If you live in Britain and are over, say, 50 years old, is it your impression that the greeting "All right?" is fairly recent? Or is it something that you've been hearing all your life?

Comment: Sorry, Sun Jul, I can't speak to that as I'm kind of stuck in the U.S. But here, "alright" as greeting/acknowledgment/blessing is frequently heard in those particular communities I've mentioned. Because this expression emerges from a primarily oral tradition, fixing a specific date for origination is well nigh impossible. Dates for this usage's occurrence in literature are inevitably after the expression has been in popular usage for some indeterminate period of time. +1 for the question, though!